# SQL First Match or just First

Tags: sql

Because this is part of a larger SQL SELECT statement, I want a wholly SQL query that selects the first item matching a criteria or, if no items match the criteria, just the first item.

I.e. using Linq I want:

```
Dim t1 = From t In Tt

Dim t2 = From t In t1 Where Criteria(t)

Dim firstIfAny = From t In If(t2.Any, t2, t1) Take 1 Select t
```

Because `If` is not part of Linq, LinqPad doesn't show a single SQL statement, but two, the second depending upon whether the `Criteria` matches any of the `Tt` values.

I know it will be `SELECT TOP 1` etc. and I can add `ORDER BY` clauses to get the specific first one I want, but I'm having trouble thinking of the most straightforward way to get the first of two criteria. <sub>(It was at exactly this point when I was able to solve this myself.)</sub>

*Seeing as I don't see an existing question for this, I will let it stand. I'm sure someone else will see the answer quickly.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone with this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeColumn = MyCriteria
 OR NOT (EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM MyTable WHERE SomeColumn = MyCriteria))
ORDER BY MyOrdering
```

My actual `SomeColumn = MyCriteria` is rather more complex of course, as well as other unrelated where clauses.

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 1 *
from (
    select top 1 *, 1 as Rank from MyTable where SomeColumn = MyCriteria
    union all
    select top 1 *, 2 as Rank from MyTable order by MyOrderColumn
) a 
order by Rank
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but then I figured that it might be more efficient to do the second select statement only if the first select statement had failed to find anything. Various ways of doing that. This will depend on how often the first one fails, I guess.

Comment: Well that is different to my implemented solution, and looks simpler in this sample SQL. Nevertheless it is not the one I've gone with.